# decoding base 64 swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift, base64, option-type

I have the following extension:

```
extension String {

    func fromBase64() -> String? {
        guard let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: self, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) else {
            return nil
        }

        return String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    }

    func toBase64() -> String? {
        guard let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
            return nil
        }

        return data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    }
}
```

And I have a base 64 encoded string: R79gQDNTt/0+cjU7pduqfA==

```
func doStuff(sample : String){

    let sampleBase64Decoded = sample.fromBase64()
}
```

When calling this function, (doStuff("R79gQDNTt/0+cjU7pduqfA==")) I get a runtime error referring to finding nil while unwrapping the optional:

```
return String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

What reasons would there be for Swift not being able to convert the base64 data to a string?

Comment: Are you sure it's valid `utf8` string?

Comment: @user28434 the string itself is encrypted and then it base 64 encoded.. So i need to base64decode it first and then decrypt it?

Comment: Well, you should decrypt it before converting data to string. Like in your `fromBase64` between `guard` line and `return` line.

Comment: @user28434 Ok thanks, I'll change around the structure of things